# Buying Memory Sticks

Tags: memory

I am about to buy some more memory for my computer. I'm looking at the following:

- XMS3 4x2048MB DDR3, PC10664 DDR1333, CAS 9-9-9-24, For Intel i5 / i7

My current Motherboard is an

- Asus P5K3 /Deluxe/WIFI-AP, Intel P35

The [supported memorylist](http://dlsvr.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5K3%20Deluxe/P5K3_Deluxe_WiFi-AP_QVL.pdf) on Asus.com is a depressingly short list.

**Questions**

Does anyone know if this combination definately wohn't work?

Does anyone have any recommendations for me to look at or read about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally the case that any DDR3 ram **should** work in any DDR3 motherboard but the only way to be absolutely certain is to find someone with an identical setup.  If you want to play it safe go to someone like crucial and use their memory selector to choose the RAM to match your motherboard.

According to corsair this is what's supposed to work with that motherboard http://www.corsair.com/configurator/product_results.aspx?id=178902

Answer (score 0):

The problem I has with my Asus motheboard was that the voltage supplied to the RAM was lower than the one needed by the RAM, thus limiting the frequency at which they operated. A subsequent BIOS update fixed that, but it took almost a year for them to come up with the update.

Maybe that's why the list is that short. Your RAM **might** work, but they might not perform as expected. Your best bet is to ask Asus support about this issue or post a question on the Asus forums; that's usually the best place for information. Also, check to see if there are any BIOS updates; they usually fix a lot of problems.